# CSS Link Background Image Not Showing up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation with a couple Image links with background images. If I make the links divs calling to the images, they show up. But when I make the links calling to the same class the background image disappears. Any help appreciated

CSS

```
#advertising  {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 465px;
    height: 65px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: url('../images/advertising.png');
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="advertising"></a>
```

Comment: show how you include the CSS file. the reason is that URLs in CSS are relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file.

Comment: css/medium.css If I preview and inspect in FireBug the image will show in the CSS location correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the images are located at `../images/`? Is that the correct path?

Comment: Yes it's the correct path

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/HKVKu/ so it must be something else. Post all relevant code please ..

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle, it's something to do with your styles.

Comment: check the console to see if there's a problem loading the resource

Comment: you sure there's not some other css pushing the elements out of view or something? What happens when you add something like top:0; left:0; to #advertising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should probably give it a `top`, `left` ... values for the  position.

2) try absolute path of the image.

3) try setting the position of one of the element containers to relative.

4) Disable ads filter :)

Comment: and try to give an absolute path for the image to know whats the problem

Comment: I've tried giving a top left, absolute image url, and still no luck

Comment: aaa an absolute position will work only if one of the element containers has position relative.

Comment: Something is going on with firefox, it's working correct in chrome

Comment: Maybe you have an ads filter in firefox :)
it happened to me once... i spent hours trying to figure it out!

Comment: @MikeTerry please mark it as the correct answer if you see it so :)

Answer (score 0):

In one of my project, I have a similar problem. If I called my css like this "css/medium.css", it doesn't work. I had to called it with a slash in the beggining "/css/medium.css"

Comment: So in other words, what you're telling him to do is check his paths, which he claims he already did.

Comment: Maybe the path is correct, but how you call the path could make the problem